# Merge two Excel sheet data into one with help of same column data

Tags: excel, python-3.x

```
Excel1
Column1     Column2         Column3
 1           A           [xyz-5536]A    
 2           B           [xyz-5537]B
 3           C           [xyz-5538]C    
 4           D           [xyz-5539]D
```

This is one type of traceability report having different items

```
Excel2
Column1        Result1      Result2
[xyz-5536]A    Pass         fail
[xyz-5537]B    fail         pass    
[xyz-5538]C    pass         fail
[xyz-5539]D    fail         pass
```

I have two excels as above , I want to create a new sheet with result as excel1 will append data by mapping ID in Square bracket and append result1 & result2

I tried it through macros

```
Column1     Column2         Column3      Result1    Result2
1            A           [xyz-5536]A     pass     fail
2            B           [xyz-5537]B     fail     pass
3            C           [xyz-5538]C     pass     fail
4            D           [xyz-5539]D     fail     pass
```

It should like above table. It should only refer one item from `column3` one time. I am new to Python.

Comment: Does the two excel data belong to the same `.xlsx` file ? (are they sheets from same file or is it 2 different files ?)

Comment: Data belongs to two different .xlsx files

Comment: And the final output is in a new file ?

Comment: yes right, final will be new file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to use the `pandas` module.

You can:

- **read** an excel file with the `read_excel` method [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You
- **merge** your data with the `merge` method [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
- **drop** duplicated columns with `drop` methods [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
- **export** your data to a new excel file with `to_excel` method [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Here the code assuming you have two excels files:

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd

# filename
filename_1 = "Excel1.xlsx"
filename_2 = "Excel2.xlsx"

# Pandas files
df_1 = pd.read_excel(filename_1)
df_2 = pd.read_excel(filename_2)
print(df_1)
#    Column1 Column2      Column3
# 0        1       A  [xyz-5536]A
# 1        2       B  [xyz-5537]B
# 2        3       C  [xyz-5538]C
# 3        4       D  [xyz-5539]D
print(df_2)
#        Column1 Result1 Result2
# 0  [xyz-5536]A    Pass    fail
# 1  [xyz-5537]B    fail    pass
# 2  [xyz-5538]C    pass    fail
# 3  [xyz-5539]D    fail    pass

# Merge the two dataframe
df_new = df_1.merge(df_2, left_on="Column3",
                   right_on="Column1", suffixes=('', '_df2'))
print(df_new)
#    Column1 Column2      Column3  Column1_df2 Result1 Result2
# 0        1       A  [xyz-5536]  A[xyz-5536]A    Pass     fail
# 1        2       B  [xyz-5537]  B[xyz-5537]B    fail     pass
# 2        3       C  [xyz-5538]  C[xyz-5538]C    pass     fail
# 3        4       D  [xyz-5539]  D[xyz-5539]D    fail     pass

# Remove the duplicated columns
df_new = df_new.drop(["Column1_df2"], axis=1)
print(df_new)
# Column1 Column2      Column3  Result1 Result2
# 0        1       A[xyz-5536]A    Pass    fail
# 1        2       B[xyz-5537]B    fail    pass
# 2        3       C[xyz-5538]C    pass    fail
# 3        4       D[xyz-5539]D    fail    pass

# Export to a new xlsx file
df_new.to_excel("new_file.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre,

Comment: Cheers, feel free to accept the answer if that solve your problem :)